# How do I double-click a borderless form to resize it?

Tags: c#, winforms, double-click, borderless

I'm writing a WinForms app with a borderless form. In a regular form, you can double-click on the title bar to toggle its WindowState between Maximized and Normal. How can I do this with a borderless form?

Here's my code for the menu's MouseDoubleClick event handler...

```
        private void MnuMain_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // The main menu (MnuMain) is where the form's title would be if the form wasn't borderless.

        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seriously, that's up to you, there's no built-in way to it.

Comment: Handling the `MouseDoubleClick` event? Of what, it depends on the layout of your Form. You could have extended the non-client area inside the client area, or maybe you have a *fake* Caption, or you could have a specific, restricted, area where mouse events can have this effect, etc. It's up to you

Comment: Jimi - I just updated my question, which includes what I've tried. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: What is `MnuMain`? Not a MainMenu component, right? Because that doesn't have...  -- What does *it doesn't work* mean here? When debugging, the event handler is hit, but the Form doesn't change state? That's not possible

Comment: If you container (MnuMain) is correct, it should be hit. If not override the DoubleClick event.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the event "MouseDoubleClick" with the event "DoubleClick".